# Apache Cordova - Chrome Not Detecting My Phone

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-3

I would like to create mobile apps using apache cordova and I have gone through the entire process of installing all the required dependencies and packages like npm, android sdk, included the paths etc.

Now, I want to be able to debug my application on my samsung galaxy s5 mini using google chrome's remote debugging, but for the life of me it just won't pick up my phone.

I have enabled usb debugging through the developer tools, both versions of chrome on my mobile and pc are up to date, my usb device drivers are up to date but this remote debugging on chrome just doesn't want to pick up my phone it is driving me up the wall.

I have also read other suggestions on the internet and on stack overflow I tried them all and nothing is working.

Please help before cordova kills me.

Comment: Thanks what's mtp and ptp

Comment: MTP and PTP is the kind of conection of the device, is camera mode or massive storage. When the device is conected to the PC, an option in the device notification bar is displayed

Comment: You need at least Android 4.4.

Answer (score 1):

Try typing in console `adb devices` (adding adb to your system path if not found). Your device should be displayed.

If not, try changing to MTP or PTP on the bar of your phone. This usually fix this issue. If still is not displayed, you have an error with your drivers, try to uninstall and reinstall